# Digamma function in expectation

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, digamma-function

I have the moment generating function
\begin{equation}
M\left(t\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+1\right)\Gamma\left(1-t\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha-t+1\right)},\ t<-1.
\end{equation}
We know that expectation and variance can be found by $E\left(X\right)=\left.\frac{d\ln M\left(t\right)}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$
and $Var\left(X\right)=\left.\frac{d^{2}\ln M\left(t\right)}{dt^{2}}\right|_{t=0}$.
How to show that
\begin{equation}
E\left(X\right)=\psi\left(\alpha+1\right)-\psi\left(1\right)\ \text{and}\ Var\left(X\right)=\psi'\left(1\right)-\psi'\left(\alpha+1\right)
\end{equation}
where $\psi\left(x\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\Gamma\left(x\right)$ is
digamma function.

at first, it seems obvious but; i couldn't get $\psi\left(\alpha+1\right)$
term in expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\ln M\left(t\right)=\ln\Gamma\left(\alpha+1\right)+\ln\Gamma\left(1-t\right)-\ln\Gamma\left(\alpha-t+1\right).
\end{equation}
Hence
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln M(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\ln\Gamma\left(1-t\right)-\frac{d}{dt}\ln\Gamma\left(\alpha-t+1\right)=-\psi(1-t)+\psi(\alpha-t+1),
$$
and at $t=0$ you get $\psi(\alpha+1)-\psi(1)$.

Comment: thanks. i had a minus mistake. a simple mistake.